# Step in Finding a Generating Function for Delannoy Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm currently reading through a proof (by Galvin) finding the generating function for the Delannoy numbers and I'm currently stuck at one step. I've been staring at this for a while, and feel that I'm just missing something.

To be clear we're going from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$. I'm at the point where we have \begin{align*}
d_{n,m}=\sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+m-k}{n}.
\end{align*}
I'm stuck at the next part.

" It follows that $d_{n,m}$ is the coefficient of $y^m$ in $\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n}{k}\frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{n+1}}$. Now the coefficient of $y^m$ in $\frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{n+1}}$ is the same as the coefficient of $y^{m-k}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-y)^{n+1}}$, which is $\binom{n+m-k}{n}\dots $"

Why is the coefficient for the last part $\binom{n+m-k}{n}$? It's presented in a way where it seems obvious, but I'm just not seeing it at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Examples_of_generating_functions_for_simple_sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
d_{n,m}= \sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}{m}} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+m-k}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply by  $y^m$ and sum on $m$ gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_n(y) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} d_{n,m} y^m &=& \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+m-k}{n} y^m \\
&=&   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{m=k}^{\infty}   \binom{n+m-k}{n} y^m \\
&=&   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} \frac{ y^k}{(1-y)^{n+1}}.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}